Convergence rate of Nadaraya–Watson estimator in Holder Space
I'm currently learning non-parametric regression using some online public materials.
Specifically, consider the model
$$
y_{i} = f_{0}(x_{i}) + \epsilon_{i}
$$
where $x_{i}\in \mathcal{X} \subset \mathbb{R}^{d}$, $y_{i}\in \mathcal{Y}\subset\mathbb{R}$, and $\epsilon_{i}$ is the error independent of $x_{i}$.
When the true mean function $f_{0}$ lies in Hölder space of order $\beta$, I believe the optimal rate for Nadaraya–Watson estimator is
$$
n^{-\frac{2\beta}{2\beta+d}},
$$
given the kernel of a certain order and the bandwidth tuned optimally.
I would like to go through the proof of this convergence rate in detail. However, the material that I can get online is concentrated at $\beta\in(0,1]$ and univariate cases. For example,

the lecture note for CMU 36-708 Statistical Methods in Machine Learning and the reference therein only covers the case for 1-Lipschitiz continuous function.
Larry Wasserman's All of Nonparametric Statistics didn't cover $\beta>1$ cases.

My question is, where can I get comprehensive proof for the convergence rate of the N-W estimator given the case $\beta>1$ and $d>1$?
